# Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 2.0.0.0 upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I changed the target framework of an old MVC app from 4.6 to 4.8. I also upgraded all Nuget packages to the latest stable versions. The Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure is upgraded to 2.0.0. The application and dependent projects all compiled successfully. I get this error when the app runs. It seems to only load 1.0.0.0. When it is downgraded to 1.0.0.0, then it wants Ninject, Version=3.3.4.0 which is upgraded to 3.3.6. There seem to be conflicts between application configuration, host configuration, and machine configuration.  The only place that mentions the DLL is in the package.config.

```html
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/myAccount/Source/repos/myOrg/Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/myName/Source/repos/myOrg/myProject/DBRN/DBRN/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\myName\Source\repos\myOrg\myProject\DBRN\DBRN\bin
Calling assembly : System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\myName\Source\repos\myOrg\myProject\DBRN\DBRN\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\myNetworkServer\Homedir$\myName\My Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Temp/1/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/f02f79de/18c40213/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Temp/1/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/f02f79de/18c40213/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myName/Source/repos/myOrg/myProject/DBRN/DBRN/bin/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace:


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.WebPages.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
   System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +39

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +890
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +167
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +133
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +178
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +746

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +122
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +737/DBRN/DBRN/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\myAccount\Source\repos\myOrg\myProject\DBRN\DBRN\bin
Calling assembly : System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\myAccount\Source\repos\myOrg\myProject\DBRN\DBRN\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: \\myNetworkServer\Homedir$\myAccount\My Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myAccount/AppData/Local/Temp/1/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/f02f79de/18c40213/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myAccount/AppData/Local/Temp/1/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/f02f79de/18c40213/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/myAccount/Source/repos/myOrg/myProject/DBRN/DBRN/bin/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace:


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.WebPages.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
   System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +39

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +890
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +167
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +133
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +178
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +746

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +122
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +737
```

Comment: Have you tried binding redirect in your application configuration file? 

      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: The above worked for us!

Comment: @user266909 did you figure this out?  I am seeing the same error, and I already have the binding redirect in my web.config file.

Comment: @JCDrumKing Did you ever get it right?

Comment: @JonKoeter Unfortunately I did not.  This error plus other competing constraints demanded that we stay at .NET 4.7.2 for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade requires editing two files.

Add dependentAssembly to `Web.config`.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

And modify these two lines in your `.csproj` file(s) to reflect current package version.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.2.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
```